# In JS dynamically set the width of the header

Tags: javascript, css

In JS I want to dynamically set the width of the header to be a certain amount of pixels specifically I want the header width to be greater than whatever is the width of the window upon loading of the document and resizing of the window.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a> <!-- Logo container -->

    <ul> <!-- Navigation menu bar options. These are fixed in terms of content. -->
        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contactus">Extras</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>          
    </ul>

</nav>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #3366FF;
    min-width: 660px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 86px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.90%;
}

#logo {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 86px;
    background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat center;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
}

#menu-icon {
    display: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 86px;
    background: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}   

a:hover#menu-icon {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #363636;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: There's no `header` in your example HTML

Comment: could you explain further? exactly how much should the header be wide?

Comment: Why not just do it in CSS: `header { width:150%; }`?

Comment: I have no idea why you would want the header to be wider than the page but simply set it wider in the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/8ym110v0/

Answer (score 0):

No javascript needed.

Here is a very simple way to render an element outside its natural block flow, achieving what I understand you to be looking for. Push way out with padding, and pull way back with negative margin. Sibling elements comply with teh flow normally.

```
.structure{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

header {
  margin-left:-999em;
  padding-left:999em;
  margin-right:-999em;
  padding-right:999em;
  background-color:pukegreen;
}
```

*Note that some structural element will need to hide the overflow.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq9gjqwh/)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on JavaScript you could do something like this with jQuery.

```
$("header").width($(window).width()+500)
```

I've added an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zpegubvL/1/) that shows the original css, this JavaScript, and a css example.  Both examples make the width 500px greater than the window's width.

The CSS version uses [Calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) to extend it 500px beyond 100%.

```
width: calc(100% + 500px);
```

I did the 500px thing because you said "set the width of the header to be a certain amount of pixels".  Had you just said that then I would have suggested using something like `width: 500px;` but you also said " I want the header width to be greater than whatever is the width of the window".
Had you left out the first part than I would have suggested something like `width: 150%;`.